# PostgreSQL error on Heroku with Ajax Datatables gem. Works 100% on local pg db. Might be an issue with query length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, postgresql, heroku, datatables

I'm having an issue with using the `ajax-datatables-rails` gem in a Rails 4.2.0 app. It's working just fine on my local, but when I try it on our staging server, I'm getting an error that looks like the query is too long.

I've confirmed that it's the sql query in general that's causing the error, since i can replicate the error by pasting in the console.

#### The ActiveRecord/ruby

```
Event.includes(:client).references(:client).past
```

#### The Query

Here's the Statement that works on local, but not heroku:

```
query = 'SELECT  "events"."id" AS t0_r0, "events"."name" AS t0_r1, "events"."description" AS t0_r2, "events"."keyword" AS t0_r3, "events"."start_datetime" AS t0_r4, "events"."end_datetime" AS t0_r5, "events"."email_subject" AS t0_r6, "events"."email_copy" AS t0_r7, "events"."text_message" AS t0_r8, "events"."hashtag" AS t0_r9, "events"."private_notes" AS t0_r10, "events"."testing" AS t0_r11, "events"."created_at" AS t0_r12, "events"."updated_at" AS t0_r13, "events"."user_id" AS t0_r14, "events"."status" AS t0_r15, "events"."event_code" AS t0_r16, "events"."interactive" AS t0_r17, "events"."client_event_tags" AS t0_r18, "events"."admin_client_tags" AS t0_r19, "events"."client_photographer_tags" AS t0_r20, "events"."event_manager_id" AS t0_r21, "events"."additional_staff" AS t0_r22, "events"."indoor_outdoor" AS t0_r23, "events"."num_attendees" AS t0_r24, "events"."attire" AS t0_r25, "events"."shot_list" AS t0_r26, "events"."frame_type" AS t0_r27, "events"."frame_design_notes" AS t0_r28, "events"."preferred_photo_sending_format" AS t0_r29, "events"."photographer_style" AS t0_r30, "events"."photo_types" AS t0_r31, "events"."requested_photographer" AS t0_r32, "events"."props" AS t0_r33, "events"."wifi_details" AS t0_r34, "events"."printing" AS t0_r35, "events"."printer_location" AS t0_r36, "events"."printer_outlet_distance" AS t0_r37, "events"."table_provided" AS t0_r38, "events"."slideshow" AS t0_r39, "events"."slideshow_description" AS t0_r40, "events"."snr" AS t0_r41, "events"."snr_design" AS t0_r42, "events"."snr_design_notes" AS t0_r43, "events"."snr_lighting" AS t0_r44, "events"."sales_person_id" AS t0_r45, "events"."sales_person_name" AS t0_r46, "events"."invoice_number" AS t0_r47, "events"."photo_delivery" AS t0_r48, "events"."photo_delivery_contact" AS t0_r49, "events"."gallery_type" AS t0_r50, "events"."gallery_email_capture" AS t0_r51, "events"."gallery_link" AS t0_r52, "events"."aws_link" AS t0_r53, "events"."photo_branding" AS t0_r54, "events"."photo_editor" AS t0_r55, "events"."client_photo_editing_notes" AS t0_r56, "events"."editor_notes" AS t0_r57, "events"."timezone" AS t0_r58, "events"."shortcut" AS t0_r59, "events"."gross_revenue" AS t0_r60, "events"."venue_id" AS t0_r61, "events"."client_id" AS t0_r62, "events"."archived" AS t0_r63, "events"."category" AS t0_r64, "events"."security_clearance" AS t0_r65, "events"."booking_id" AS t0_r66, "events"."load_out" AS t0_r67, "events"."twitter_message" AS t0_r68, "events"."frames" AS t0_r69, "events"."tilt_funded" AS t0_r70, "events"."sales_notes" AS t0_r71, "events"."operations_notes" AS t0_r72, "events"."pipedrive_deal_url" AS t0_r73, "events"."package" AS t0_r74, "events"."has_survey" AS t0_r75, "events"."has_waiver" AS t0_r76, "events"."facebook_message" AS t0_r77, "events"."slideshow_url" AS t0_r78, "events"."gear_pickup_datetime" AS t0_r79, "events"."gear_pickup_location" AS t0_r80, "events"."gear_tracking_number" AS t0_r81, "events"."official_title" AS t0_r82, "events"."meal_during_activation" AS t0_r83, "events"."break_during_activation" AS t0_r84, "events"."vibe" AS t0_r85, "events"."approach" AS t0_r86, "events"."fake" AS t0_r87, "events"."manager_call_time" AS t0_r88, "events"."staff_call_time" AS t0_r89, "events"."allow_multiple_uploads" AS t0_r90, "events"."onsite_contact_first_name" AS t0_r91, "events"."onsite_contact_last_name" AS t0_r92, "events"."onsite_contact_company" AS t0_r93, "events"."onsite_contact_email" AS t0_r94, "events"."onsite_contact_phone" AS t0_r95, "events"."should_notify_for_changes" AS t0_r96, "events"."site_manager_id" AS t0_r97, "events"."payment_status" AS t0_r98, "events"."needs_info" AS t0_r99, "events"."shoot_type" AS t0_r100, "clients"."id" AS t1_r0, "clients"."first_name" AS t1_r1, "clients"."last_name" AS t1_r2, "clients"."phone_number" AS t1_r3, "clients"."company" AS t1_r4, "clients"."notes" AS t1_r5, "clients"."created_at" AS t1_r6, "clients"."updated_at" AS t1_r7, "clients"."email" AS t1_r8, "clients"."pref_contact_method" AS t1_r9, "clients"."braintree_customer_id" AS t1_r10, "clients"."user_id" AS t1_r11, "clients"."corporate" AS t1_r12 FROM "events" LEFT OUTER JOIN "clients" ON "clients"."id" = "events"."client_id" WHERE (end_datetime < "2017-02-21 22:12:44.071050") AND "events"."archived" = "f"  ORDER BY clients.last_name DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0'
```

[It's really long, so here's a gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/afxjzs/c44a0868a95b3ed92eec1c914e08804f/raw/264e26f12d013f035a510ffcba48a66a11f7d435/SQL%2520Error)

Since the error i'm getting seems to occur in the middle of a string, it leads me to believe it's related to the overall length of the query.

#### The Error

[Gist of full error output](https://gist.github.com/afxjzs/f976c992826a9e710846365b62440b99)
The first line of that is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column events.["user", "venue", "client", "booking", "sales_person", "event_m does not exist
```

but `event_m` is just part of a column name, `event_manager_id` which has a `belongs_to` relationship with a `User`. This sql is generated by active record, so i'm not sure what the issue would be.

#### PG Versions

My local is actually running a slightly older version of Postgres
Local:

```
=> "PostgreSQL 9.4.8 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit"
```

Heroku:

```
=> "PostgreSQL 9.4.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit"
```

Do you guys have any idea what could be causing this? Or even better, how to fix it? I've tried only selecting certain fields on the `Event` model but that doesn't help. I've used the `ajax-datatables-gem` and implemention on other models and it works fine. It's only the `Event` model that is giving me issues.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error says that table does not exist..hope you ran rake db:migrate.Moreover,you can open the rails console on heroku...Run heroku run rails c...and verify your db there too.

Comment: you have to make sure that have these columns. I am using this gem with PG on production in serveral project as far as good

Comment: @Milind It's saying that because it's reading half of a string tho. There haven't been schema changes in a while, and this is an identical schema to my local, which works 100%

Comment: Try running this in Rails console on Heroku `Event.select(:id).includes(:client).references(:client).past`. Is there any error?

Comment: @MichałMłoźniak Yes, there was an error: https://gist.github.com/afxjzs/123deec6126fcda17061eb834ec7973c ( also tried with `.all` instead of `.past` and same error

Comment: @afxjzs Right now it is impossible to see the whole query. Can you also post output from `Event.select(:id).includes(:client).references(:client).to_sql`?

Comment: @MichałMłoźniak https://gist.github.com/afxjzs/dbf187c8724d01a87c6f2e3f19f28655 <-- that's the output from that command in the console